# Cakephp 2 request data and model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 2 models. Order & OrderProduct

When an Order to is added, Im trying to manipulate the OrderProduct data in the beforeValidate() of the Order Model but unsuccessfully.

I've tried. (Both in Order model)

```
function beforeValidate() 
{
    parent::beforeValidate();
    $this->data['OrderProduct']['total'] = 1000;
    return true;
}

function beforeValidate() 
{
    parent::beforeValidate();
    CakeRequest::data('OrderProduct.total', 1000);
    return true;
}
```

But the OrderProduct data isnt being modified when viewed from the controller after a failed transaction (!this->saveAll()).

Could any suggest a alternative solution with out manually setting the data in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

Try $this->request->data['OrderProduct']['total'] = 1000;

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a successful save somewhere to change a record in the DB.  If you do a save and it fails, then the value you are editing will be discarded.

FYI, the first one should work for setting a value in $this->data.

All you need now is a transaction that doesn't fail. i.e.

```
$this->save($this->data);
```

Also note, the call to save will need either more information such as an id, or you'll need to read a record first and then save it.